# how to substring with word boundary for a long html content for preview (preserving format) in web using java?

Tags: java, html

I am trying to display a quick summary of a long html message sent by user. I would like to do this in java rather than javascript. How can I achieve this? I have looked at jsoup and htmlunit but can not find the method that does it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `jsoup` you can parse the document, select the inner element where the text content is too long and replace its text content with an excerpt.

- [Parse a document](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/parse-document-from-string)
- [Find an element](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)
- [Extract the text content](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html)
- Compute a replacement string
- [Set the new text content](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/modifying-data/set-text)

It is all in their doc.

All in one it results in:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String html = "<html><head><title>First parse</title></head><body><p>Parsed HTML into a doc.</p></body></html>";
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        Element pTag = doc.select("body > p").first(); // the p tag
        String pContent = pTag.text();
        pContent = pContent.substring(0, 7) + "... (too long)";
        pTag.text(pContent);
        System.out.println(doc);
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>First parse</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>Parsed ... (too long)</p>
 </body>
</html>
```